# visual format constraints in iOs 8

Tags: ios8, constraints

I'm trying to add visual contraints to my view. In iOS 7 everything works fine but with 8.0 no.

My code

```
 NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_view1, _view2);

[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[_view1]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]; 
constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[_view2(200.0)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]]; 

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[_view1(200.0)]-10-[_view2(200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

The view1 after apply contraints has 0 width.
I've searched for apple docs but nothing referes that this method is deprecated.

Any ideas?